# Get summary results from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

I have a table:

```
TestType  TimeStamp             Result
1         2020-06-23 14:20:07Z  1
1         2020-06-23 14:20:07Z  2
1         2020-06-23 14:20:11Z  1
2         2020-06-23 14:20:11Z  1
2         2020-06-23 14:20:11Z  1
2         2020-06-23 14:20:11Z  1
3         2020-06-23 14:20:15Z  2
1         2020-06-23 14:20:23Z  2
1         2020-06-23 14:20:23Z  1
```

where Result values are:

```
1 - Pass
2 - Fail
```

Is it possible to write such a query to retrieve distinct rows where the Result would be the worst value?
From the table above I expect the query to return the next dataset:

```
TestType  TimeStamp             Result
1         2020-06-23 14:20:07Z  2
1         2020-06-23 14:20:11Z  1
2         2020-06-23 14:20:11Z  1
3         2020-06-23 14:20:15Z  2
1         2020-06-23 14:20:23Z  2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select testType, timestamp, max(result) result
from mytable
group by testType, timestamp
```

If you need to handle more values, it might be simpler to use window functions:

```
select testType, timestamp, result
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number over(
            partition by testType, timestamp
            order by case result 
                when 3 then 1   -- fail
                when 7 then 2   -- pass
                when 1 then 3   -- unknown
            end
        ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, great! But what if Result values would be different and max() would not return the right result? And also we could have other possible values as a Result. Let's say that Pass=7 and Fail=3 and Unknown=1. Can we have some kind of mapping to get the worst result based on the mapped value?